# How to identify the source of a package version in the Manifest generated by maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: java, maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm creating an OSGI bundle from a Maven module with the use of maven-bundle-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
                *
            </Import-Package>
            <Export-Package>
                my.bundle.packages
            </Export-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a dependency which exposes *javax.annotation*. Because of this, the generated Manifest contains `Import-Package: javax.annotation;version="[3.2,4)"`

How can I find out which dependency exports this package? By using `mvn dependency:list` I've been able to exclude a few dependencies (com.google.code.findbugs:annotations and com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305), but still the version range remains.
I've been looking in the Manifest-files of the direct dependencies, but have not found any other jar exporting javax.annotation.

Note: I could add a dependency to javax.annotation:com.springsource.javax.annotation and the Manifest would correctly import javax.annotation version 1.0.0, but this shouldn't be necessary and I personally would find it cleaner to exclude the unknown dependency.

Comment: Which dependency jar contains the package javax.annotations?

Comment: None of them do, but there might be a nested dependency that does. This package is part of the jdk and at runtime the springsource-bundle is deployed

Comment: The 3.x range of the import might point to spring if you use spring 3.x. Can you post your pom content?

Comment: I don't use spring 3.x. The pom just contains a list of dependencies and the plugin above

Comment: the version might be caused by the bundle version if no package version is specified. You can override the version wiht <Import-Paclage>javax.annotation;version=0,*</Import-Package>

Comment: Indeed, I can force it, but I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I find out which dependency exports this package?

If you have *nix console and `bnd`command line tool installed you could try:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath | grep jar | tr ':' ' ' | xargs bnd find -e 'javax.annotation'
```

There is probably a better way to do this but it's a staring point

Comment: This has been helpful in a way. The dependencies which I identified before are the only ones that expose that package. However the Manifest still specifies the incorrect version.

Comment: Turns out I can't read the Manifest correctly. This command helped me find the problematic dependencies and does list the jars that expose the package